# Is there an English word for "removing stem from a cilantro" (coriander)

Tags: terminology

My native language has a word for that process hence I am curious to find out if English has one.  I searched for it on the Internet without success.  Apart from "removing stem", I found "removing leaves" from cilantro.

Comment: Um, what process? Why would you remove the stem from cilantro? Is this something that's unique to cilantro, or would parsley be treated the same way? What do you do with the cilantro after applying this mysterious process? Pictures might be good.

Comment: I'd suggest looking on a cooking show or website and find a description of the process there to find out the name.  For instance 'julienning' is a type of cutting for vegetables and would be easier to find the term there than in a general site.  There is a Stack Exchange specific to Cooking that would be a good bet.

Comment: Checkout this video where Paula shows how to quickly remove the leaves from cilantro - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY3BcyvxklQ  I haven't used this 'fast' technique yet.   I simply remove the top part of each piece, one at a time.  I came across this video when I was trying to look for the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In winemaking, **destemming** is the process of removing the stems from the grapes, and the same term is usable for coriander.

[Dictionary.com meaning:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/destemming)

> **Verb (used with object), de·stemmed, de·stem·ming.**
>
> to remove the stem from (a fruit or vegetable); stem.

Comment: What language?  What is the word?  I'd love to hear it.

Comment: In Marathi we say "कोथिंबिर निवडणे".  The first word means 'cilantro'.  The second word when used with the first implies the process of removing stems.  The closest English word I can think of is "sort".  When used as "तांदूळ निवडणे", it means to 'remove small pebbles/impurities' from grains such as rice (तांदूळ) before cooking them.

Answer (score 2):

In food-prep, I've seen it mostly referred to as "stemming" which might appear counter to and the opposite action of "de-stemming".  However, they are not.

> 7. to remove the stem or stems from (a fruit, etc.) - Collins English Dictionary

Also, "stripping" as in "stripping the leaves off a branch of a tree"